# Unable to apply PATCH_SUPEE-7405 to CE 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, supee-7405

I get a couple of errors, the first one the patch fails on the first hunk for  app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php

The second error is it can't find the file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php On closer examination, I don't even have an app/code/core/Zend/Xml directory in my installation!

I don't see any prerequisite patches listed for SUPEE-7405, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered there are two previous patches I had not applied, SUPEE-6482 and SUPEE-6788. Of those it is now obvious that SUPEE-6788 is a prerequisite to SUPEE-7405.